# Do factions/civilisations in ETW have unique characteristics?

Tags: empire-total-war

Besides "racial" units, I seem to be observing some other unique traits to different factions. For example, I noticed in a custom battle that British line infantry seem to have different stats from, for example, French line infantry. On another instance, I just started the Prussian grand campaign and noticed that Austrian line infantry have 200 men as opposed to the normal 160. Are these all "racial bonuses"?

Is there a complete list of such racial bonuses for all playable factions (and maybe non-playables as well if they exist)? This isn't just limited to differences between military units - perhaps some factions have bonuses or penalties to things such as research rate, relations, public order etc? For the sake of completeness, the full list of racial units for each faction can be included in the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell you about campaign map bonuses, but for units, the biggest differences are probably between line infantry. Sweden, Spain, Poland-Lithuania, the United Provinces and the US all share a "basic" unit. The Russians exchange accuracy and reloading skills for melee skills and a lower cost, the Austrians get larger, worse units, the British and Prussians have faster reloading, more expensive units that are better at melee defense and charge bonus respectively, and the French have units that are better in melee. Other than that, Sweden tends to have larger, more expensive cavalry, Austria has just better (but much more expensive) Cuirassiers, and Prussia has very slightly cheaper pikes. Artillery seems to be consistent across all European factions. Light infantry is identical for all factions save the Austrians, who replace it with jaegers, which are better. Grenadiers also change: Spain has cheaper ones, Russia cheaper, less accurate ones with superior melee stats, Prussia just better units (that are also cheaper than usual), and everyone else gets lumped with the same.

In terns of uniques, then Britain has loads, mostly better line infantry, most factions have at least one unit of elite line infantry a la Maison du Roi, Austria has light infantry coming out of its earholes (okay, like two, but still), and there are several elite cavalry units, such as two "Garde de Corps"'s (one French, the other Prussian), the Polish Winged Lancers, and the cheaper, medium-quality Haakepelitta (Sweden) .

Oh, and the Ottomans? Terrible, awful infantry until late game (when they get just about OK copies of European units) and good artillery and passable cav. The Indians get better inf and elephants.

I've probably missed out loads, so here is a link to a complete list of units. http://wiki.totalwar.com/index.php?title=Category:Empire:_Total_War_Units

Comment: Well, I guess this will have to do. Wonder if there are any non-units bonuses? I'll mark you as the answer if no others come up. Thanks!